# Getting Asset FolderId

Tags: templating, assets, filter, files

I need to list out the image options from a specific assets folder for users to select from. Previously, I accomplished that like this:

```
{% set folder_id = 5 %}

{% for image in craft.assets.kind('image').folderId(folder_id).order('filename') %}

    {# do stuff, like print image.filename #}

{% endfor %}
```

And to get the folder ID pre-2.5, I could inspect the folders menu when viewing assets in CP. Now, that appears to be gone in Craft 2.5+ and struggling to find the ID. I'm assuming there must be a way to view the folderId as Craft has a `folderId()` filter for `craft.assets`.

Does anyone know?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always check the `craft_assetfolders` table in the database, find the folder name you're looking for and grab its `id`.

And it's probably just a typo in your original code, you're setting the folder ID to a variable named `folder_id`, but you're passing `id` into `.folderId(id)`.

Comment: Yeah, typo, sorry! Was just typing out an example and not really focused on it. Just looked through the `craft_assetfolders` table and found them. Thanks!